# How to change the service root in webapi odata v3?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-api-management, asp.net-web-api-odata

Have webapi odata v3 endpoint implemented with Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData, exposed under API management, how do I change the service root path, instead of returning the azurewebsite one return the api management URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `<redirect-content-urls/>` policy in an outbound policy to update the URLs.  If that doesn't work as you need, you can use the `<find-and-replace/>` policy.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#MaskURLSContent

Comment: Loved it! So easy to fix!